# Dll Injection Fail to Chrome's "Job Processes"

Tags: google-chrome, jobs, dll-injection

I am trying to inject dll to chrome.exe.
I tried many ways of injecting dll such as Process Hacker, Cheat Engine, [InjDll](http://www.reversecore.com/76) ...
But all dll injectors failed to inject library into some processes.
Image From Process Hacker:

[image]

What I found is dll-injecting fails into brown-colored processes, and brown-color means Job Process.
How can I manage dll-injecting to all chrome processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that they are a JOB the problem is that they are running at **LOW INTEGRITY LEVEL** (process explorer can show it)
and they haven't disk access so you can not read from disk the dll :)

how to fix?
1-SetWindowsHookEx based dll injection, with my injector it worked (other ways not)
2-ManualMap, maybe it is a bit extreme but that's always work :)

Comment: Do You say You can use SetWindowsHookEx also on the Chrome's processes? They do not have GUI. Which hook did You specifically use then?

Comment: Is ManualMap method You mention something like this: https://github.com/stephenfewer/ReflectiveDLLInjection ?